# Clojurescript with Reagent, instrumenting a component function makes the component constantly re-render with random generated props

Tags: function, clojurescript, specifications, instrumentation, reagent

I have a Reagent component with a spec and I try to instrument it to verify properties during development:

```
(ns generic-components.numeric-input.view
  (:require
   [reagent.core :as r]
   [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]

   [clojure.test.check.generators]
   [clojure.test.check.properties]
   [clojure.test.check]
   [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest]
   ))

(s/def ::input-attr map?)
(s/def ::message-attr map?)

(s/def ::placeholder string?)

(s/def ::display-value string?)
(s/def ::message string?)
(s/def ::is-valid boolean?)
(s/def ::is-disabled boolean?)

(s/def ::handle-change
  (s/fspec
   :args (s/cat :val (s/or :string string? :nil nil?))
   :ret any?))

(s/def ::handle-blur
  (s/fspec
   :args (s/cat :val (s/or :string string? :nil nil?))
   :ret any?))

(s/def ::props (s/keys :req-un [::display-value
                                ::is-valid
                                ::handle-blur
                                ::handle-change]
                       :opt-un [::input-attr
                                ::message-attr
                                ::message
                                ::placeholder
                                ::is-disabled]))

(defn numeric-input [props]
  (println props)
  [:<>
   [:input (merge
            (:input-attr props)
            (select-keys props [:placeholder])
            {:class (r/class-names [(-> props :input-attr :class)
                                    (when
                                     (= false (:is-valid props))
                                      "invalid")])
             :value (:display-value props)
             :on-change #((:handle-change props) (-> % .-target .-value))
             :on-blur #((:handle-blur props) (-> % .-target .-value))}
            (when (::is-disabled props) {:disabled true}))]
   (when-let [message (:message props)]
     [:div (:message-attr props) message])])

(s/fdef numeric-input
  :args (s/cat :props ::props)
  :ret any?)

(stest/instrument `numeric-input)
```

I render it as follows:

```
(defn root []
  (let [input-val (r/atom "dv")]
    (fn [] [:div#app-root
     [:div.main-logo "Welcome to Crazy Ivan Motors"]
     [:div.screens
      [numeric-input {:display-value (or @input-val "") 
                      :is-valid true
                      :handle-change #(reset! input-val %)
                      :handle-blur #(reset! input-val %)}]]])))
```

When I open the page, either I get exceptions upon exceiptions, or the page renders, but then component starts re-rendering as fast as possible with random strings. Here is console.log output for props (I'm getting dozens per second):

```
{:display-value 5iMJEW6wq587mS2s, :is-valid true, :handle-change #object[Function], :handle-blur #object[Function]} core.cljs:198:60
{:display-value , :is-valid true, :handle-change #object[Function], :handle-blur #object[Function]} 2 core.cljs:198:60
{:display-value PR2JMw9G6UJ, :is-valid true, :handle-change #object[Function], :handle-blur #object[Function]} core.cljs:198:60
```

I know about generative capabilities of spec, but I can't figure out, why/how are they activating in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, problem is caused by the following:

```clj
(s/def ::handle-change
  (s/fspec
   :args (s/cat :val (s/or :string string? :nil nil?))
   :ret any?))

(s/def ::handle-blur
  (s/fspec
   :args (s/cat :val (s/or :string string? :nil nil?))
   :ret any?))
```

It looks like having `fspec` for a map key causes `valid?` to test that key via generation when testing containing map. Switched to

```
(s/def ::handle-change fn?)
(s/def ::handle-blur fn?)
```